How do I set the selectedMessage when using MSMessageLiveLayout
I have a trivial MSMessagesAppViewController from which I'd like to send a message with an MSMessageLiveLayout. Here's what the message composition looks like:
var components = URLComponents()
components.query = "hello=world"
let alternateLayout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
alternateLayout.image = UIImage(named: "Example Preview Image")
alternateLayout.caption = "Hello, world!"
let layout = MSMessageLiveLayout(alternateLayout: alternateLayout)
let message = MSMessage(session: MSSession())
message.url = components.url!
message.layout = alternateLayout
self.activeConversation?.insert(message)

I've set up my MSMessagesAppViewController to display a separate view when conversation.selectedMessage is set in willBecomeActive, and everything to do with sending and rendering messages from the extensions works.
Question: how MSMessageLiveLayout are transcript previews are supposed to set the activateConversation.selectedMessage? By default, tapping on the live layout message does nothing (whereas using MSMessageTemplateLayout triggers willSelect and didSelect). I could add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the transcript view, but what am I supposed to invoke in the callback to open my extension?
